# machinekey validation using 3DES

Tags: encryption, viewstate, 3des, machinekey

I am getting the error on the following machinekey when using validationkey & decryption key using 3DES validation. it works when i removed both. what's the best approach when using 3DES?

```
<machineKey       validationKey="AD34B95FCD4C35848217F74E18AAC1DB029CB2265C46ECCA6E1A2F558B6A2EDFF3AF81FE84F39935F44152B3B6978F843659B1D9370C9D1F7ABAF3B687C726A2"
        decryptionKey="0932BBEB28DFA274EFBE9D9A2BBDF7DDBDA08B56BFD186F2512DD06AC7DBD16E"
        validation="3DES" decryption="AES"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your validation key to a valid 3DES key, they have specific length requirements.
Looks like your key is for SHA1.

Take a look at this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx)

> "For SHA1, set the validationKey to 64 bytes (128 hexadecimal
>   characters).  For AES, set the decryptionKey to 32 bytes (64
>   hexadecimal characters).  For 3DES, set the decryptionKey to 24 bytes
>   (48 hexadecimal characters)."

You may want to use [this tool](http://www.a2zmenu.com/utility/Machine-Key-Generator.aspx) to generate your key specifying the algorithm